# creating comobject for AccessObjects

Tags: powershell, ms-access

I am trying to create a powershell 'AccessObject' comobject for my MS Access app. Basically, I will trying to create a powershell script that gets queries in a database and the tables and/or queries a particular query depends on. To do that i will need to have an instance of the MS Access 'AccessObject' and 'DependencyInfo' classes in my powershell script. I have attached a snippet of the function i intend to use. This is not the complete function, please note. All i want is to know how to create an instance of the DependencyInfo and AccessObjects in powershell.

```html
function getQueries([string] $database)
{
    $dbEng = New-Object -ComObject DAO.DBEngine.120
     
    $AccessApp= New-Object -ComObject Access.Application
 
    $Dependency = $AccessApp.DependencyInfo
    $AccessObject=$AccessApp.AccessObjects

 ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All i want is to know how to create an instance of the DependencyInfo
>   and AccessObjects in powershell.

The following creates a new Access process, opens a local accdb file, and retrieves the dependencies for a given form:

```
$db = new-object -ComObject 'Access.Application'
$db.OpenCurrentDatabase('C:\temp\deezNutz.accdb')
$dependency_info = $db.Application.CurrentProject().AllForms('frm_person').GetDependencyInfo()
foreach ($dependency in $dependency_info.Dependencies) { $dependency.FullName }
$db.CloseCurrentDatabase()
$db.Application.DoCmd.Quit()
```

If you're trying to pro grammatically manipulate the objects in a Microsoft Access database e.g., forms, reports, queries, etc. Your best bet is to search for solutions using VBA then convert those to Powershell. For this example, I first wrote the solution in VBA then converted it to Powershell.

Comment: Thanks @Lord Adam. This was really helpful. In my case i had to modify the logic a little bit.                                                                          
  $AccessApp= New-Object -ComObject 'Access.Application'
    $AccessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase($database)

    $AccessApp.Application.SetOption("Track Name AutoCorrect Info", $true)                                                                                                    $QryDependency = $AccessApp.Application.CurrentData.AllQueries.Item($query.Name).GetDependencyInfo().

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Lord Adam. This was really helpful. In my case i had to modify the logic a little bit:

```html
$AccessApp= New-Object -ComObject 'Access.Application'
$AccessApp.OpenCurrentDatabase($database)

 $AccessApp.Application.SetOption("Track Name AutoCorrect Info", $true)
    
 $QryDependency = $AccessApp.Application.CurrentData.AllQueries.Item($query.Name).GetDependencyInfo()
 
  ForEach($di in $QryDependency.Dependencies)
      {
              $QryObjects= $QryObjects + $di.Name +","
      }
```